# "Telemetry" task was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am getting the following error when I create new .net core project on VS2017:

> Error MSB4036 The "Telemetry" task was not found. Check the following:
>   1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly
>   declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files
>   located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin"
>   directory.    ConsoleApp8 C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets    106

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling .net core?

Answer (score 1):

This error looks like you were trying to use the MSBuild version of an older Visual Studio version.

Be sure to only use `dotnet` commands or the MSBuild version distributed with Visual Studio or other self-contained MSBuild 15 distributions (e.g. by JetBrains).

Comment: Thanks!! I installed VS 2013 and VS2017 side by side,
I uninstalled VS2013.
and now .net core projects are successfully loaded and complied